# Expand div to get remaining width with css

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I need help, I have a 4 div elements, three of them have fixed width, one of them needs to be with auto width. Second element needs to have variable width.

For example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">
  </div>
  <div id="second">
  </div>
  <div id="third">
  </div>
  <div id="fourth">
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#first,#second,#third,#fourth{
  float:left;
}
#second{
  width:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#first,#third,#fourth{
  width: 200px;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please post your CSS too

Comment: What have you tried? This looks pretty simple to achieve with css, set widths for the 3 id's you want and not for the second element (or set its width to 100%)

Comment: Yeah, we need to see the CSS. My bet is that the wrapper has a set width, and the second inner div needs to stretch outside that. Is that right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using `display: table-cell` **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QcQKC/)**

#### CSS

```
#wrapper .item{ 
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 150px; 
    min-width: 150px; 
    border: 1px solid #777; 
    background: #eee; 
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper #second{
    width: 100%
}
```

#### Markup

```
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="first" class="item">First
     </div>
     <div id="second" class="item">Second
     </div>
     <div id="third" class="item">Third
     </div>
     <div id="fourth" class="item">Fourth
     </div>
  </div>
```

## Update

## Float version

#### CSS

```
     #wrapper div{background:#eee; border: 1px solid #777; min-width: 200px;}
     #first{
        float: left;
     }
     #wrapper #second{
        width: auto;
        background: #ffc;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
        min-width: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
     #first, #third, #fourth{
        width: 200px;
     }

     #third, #fourth{float: right;}
```

**Markup**, **Move #second to end**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="first">First</div>
     <div id="third">Third</div>
     <div id="fourth">Fourth</div>
     <div id="second">Second</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried it, it works fine. But I have a problem when I put display:table-cell, actually I have a problem in chrome. I need solution with display block. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

i think you might be looking for this one:

This is for your reference if you are having such a thing then you can do the trick with this, i exactly don't know how your css looks like but this is basic idea.

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Npedg/)

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    width:960px;
}
#first
{
    float:left;
    width:240px;
}
#second
{
    width:240px;
    float:left;
}
#third
{
    float:left;
    width:240px
}
```

Here your last `div` width will be set automatically.